# Cordova Oauth with google and Server Side calls

Tags: cordova, google-oauth, server-side

I have an Ionic/Cordova Application. I use $cordovaOauth.google to connect with google. I just have in return the access token. I send this to my server side.

I need to access user information even if the access token is not valid. I read that i need to use the Refresh Token. But i don't have.

Can i get a refresh token from an access token ?

Comment: look for something like off line access in the documentation.  Its what forces the Authentication server to return a refreshtoken.  sorry cant help with cordova

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying for instance : [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) and it looks very promising.
I assume that you can retreive all these information there ;)

Answer (score 0):

With $cordovaOauth, it's just possible to take a token.
Or in my case, after search in google api docs, i need getting a authenfication code end send it to server side. So i rewrited code by :

```
.factory('$googleApi', function($http,  $q) {
    return {
        connect: function(clientId, appScope, options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            window.cordova=true;
            if(window.cordova) {
                  var redirect_uri = "http://localhost/callback";
                    if(options !== undefined) {
                        if(options.hasOwnProperty("redirect_uri")) {
                            redirect_uri = options.redirect_uri;
                        }
                    }
                    var browserRef = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&scope=' + appScope.join(" ") + '&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&response_type=code', '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
                    browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", function(event) {
                        if((event.url).indexOf(redirect_uri) === 0) {
                            browserRef.removeEventListener("exit",function(event){});
                            browserRef.close();
                            var code = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
                            if(code) {
                                  deferred.resolve({ code: code });
                            } else {
                                deferred.reject("Problem authenticating");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    browserRef.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                        deferred.reject("The sign in flow was canceled");
                    });
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Cannot authenticate via a web browser");
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```